# 431 Request Header Fields Too Large using query parameter

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http, visual-studio-code

I am getting 431 Request Header Fields Too Large when encoding an object into a query param like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/object/1501?data=%7B%22id%22%3A%22ke9rd78g%22%...continues
```

I am debugging an Angular app in Chrome using Visual Code.
Is there a way to allow larger request headers?

Comment: There is a limit to the size of header values. Is there a reason why you are sending the data in headers instead of body?

Comment: Is backend node.js ?

Comment: Hi @MuhammadKamran the reason is that I am rendering a graph and I want to be able to share the url with the current graph objects.

Comment: hi @pc_coder the backend is ASP.Net core API but I assumed it doesn´t matter here because I am not calling the backend when the error occurs.